# Word(s) to describe the emotion behind disappointedly looking over ones glasses?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say a friend asks a particularly dumb question (e.g., "what's the phone number for 1-800-Flowers?"), and you just stare at them with a look that says "you've got to be kidding me."

There's definitely surprise and disappointment in the look, but with a little amusement and condescension mixed in.

Are there are any words that succinctly describe this look/emotion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to give someone a quizzical look.

expressive of puzzlement, curiosity or disbelief

[quizzical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quizzical)

Examples:
But in general, as befits a covert operative, his tone is quizzical and low-key, rather than bombastic and judgmental. For anyone schooled in blackboard economics, "The Undercover Economist" succeeds in taking the chalk dust out of the subject. **The Economist**

It makes up for the quizzical glances that leap my way when I stow away on scriptwriting courses or lectures on psychology. **The Guardian**

[Ludwid guru is a great tool! See the two examples above.](https://ludwig.guru/s/quizzical)

Comment: I actually think 'disbelief' itself describes the expression really well! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "**askance**" would aptly portray it as a "look of incredible disbelief" (*Are you serious...?*).

[TFD - askance](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/askance)

Answer (score 0):

A single word term fitting that definition is not likely to be be found in any dictionary; however, there seems to be no problem in finding two-word compounds. Here is one that would do.

- *benign bemusement* (with benign bemusement)

(This one is a rather well known collocation ([ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22benign%20bemusement%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)).)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to predict what emotions lurk in the heart of a speaker.
But if something is accurately describable as "disappointedly looking over one's glasses",
then I think there's no reason not to speak of "the emotion behind" it as ***disappointment***.

Comment: I get it—it wasn't a perfectly phrased title

Answer (score 0):

Looking or peering over one's glasses is a non-verbal gesture for which there are no words — except to describe the action. The gesture conveys a sense of criticism, derision, or judgement. *Body Language For Dummies* describes it like this:

> If someone peers over the tops of her glasses at you, don't be
> surprised if you feel scrutinised. Peering down on another person
> conveys a critical or judgemental attitude. The glasses underscore or
> highlight the action.
>  <sub>Source:[Body Language For
> Dummies](https://books.google.com/books?id=7xzhVIwIqSMC&lpg=PA182&ots=BXPIwKRWFJ&dq=look%20over%20one%27s%20glasses%20body%20language&pg=PA182#v=onepage&q=look%20over%20one%27s%20glasses%20body%20language&f=false)</sub>

The good news is that while helpful, the glasses are not necessary for this gesture, or the gesture you describe that includes surprise and amusement. Minus the glasses, the adjective *bemused* (or the noun *bemusement*) works quite well here: *a bemused look* (*a look of bemusement*).

In addition to a sense of surprise and amusement, the word embodies a facial expression that expresses [mockery](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mockery) or derision:

> [**bemused**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bemused)
> *adjective*
> **3 :** having or showing feelings of wry amusement especially from something that is surprising or perplexing
>
> [**wry**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wry)
> *adjective*
> **2 :** made by a deliberate distortion of the facial muscles often to express irony or mockery
>
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com)</sub>

[See results from *Corpus of Contemporary American English* for *bemused look*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=99742345). Of course, *bemused* has other senses too, so not all of those entries may apply, but here's one example:

> 28: *And who can forget the bemused look on Ravi Shankar's face as he
> watched George Harrison struggle to control the sitar?*

For reference, here is an image of something like what you described in your question:

[image: A man looking over his glasses with a furrowed brow, captioned with: You have to be kidding me.]

Source: [Memes Monkey](https://www.memesmonkey.com)

Putting it all together, perhaps:

> *He peered over his glasses with a bemused look.*

Answer (score 0):

Quite literally, one is [looking down one's nose at](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/look_down_one%27s_nose_at.) the other person.

(Lexico powered by Oxford)

> regard (someone) with a feeling of superiority.